# Is this NHibernate sample still valid?

Tags: nhibernate, sample

Or the concepts/best practices used there are now deprecated? I'm just starting to use NHibernate and I'm having a hard time finding good real life samples.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see for the dates the author (Billy McCafferty) didn't update it in a long time. There is so much more on the NHibernate ground now but most of the concepts in that article still apply.
You may want to checkout additional sources like:

- http://nhforge.org/
- http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/
- http://fluentnhibernate.org/

If you are using NHibernate in web applications, Billy McCafferty built an excelent framework on top of NHibernate and ASP.net MVC. http://www.sharparchitecture.net/

And this open source app is an awesome sample: http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/